# What is the map of Barsoom that Carl Sagan had outside his office?

Tags: john-carter, carl-sagan

Read the [wiki article on Barsoom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsoom#Burroughs.E2.80.99_influence) that references the fact that Carl Sagan had a map of barsoom.

I can't find a very good one on the Internet and even if I did, it would be extremely cool to have the same one that Carl Sagan did.  So, just in case someone can find maps that match the time period, that might answer the question, even if it's impossible to find the exact map.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, great question. All I could find is this [link](http://www.erbzine.com/mag28/2807.html) with many maps of Barsoom on it.
(So, take your pick!)
One of the pictures is by cartographer Larry Ivie apparently drawn in the 1960s.
Here's a [closeup](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-D8zWICYLbBE/UOtQmrRenPI/AAAAAAAACqY/Ak-92wEZcVQ/s1600/barsoom1b.jpg) of the image.
If I'm reading the wiki correctly, Dr Sagan was at Cornell from 1976-1996, therefore this map could be a contender but as you stated this might be impossible to find.

Answer (score 3):

**This is reputed to be [Edgar Rice Burroughs](http://www.edgarriceburroughs.ca/)' first map of [Barsoom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsoom). Since this map was created there have been multiple attempts to map Barsoom from various writers and publishers telling stories on Barsoom.**

[image]

> Edgar Rice Burroughs drew crude maps to locate his John Carter's adventures, but he was not a cartographer.  Moreover, his work constitutes entirely a second hand account.  He was not the source, rather, he related tales told by John Carter.   Accordingly, as a dedicated and prolific scribe, he may be forgiven for the occasional error.
>
> In the 1940's a substantially more elaborate map was drafted, intended to overlay ERB's Barsoom over the map of Mars as it was known then.   That original Map of Mars has turned out to be highly inaccurate, and so the superimposition of Barsoomian locations must be taken as equally inaccurate.   In fact, the most compelling thing about the 1940's map is that it was an attempt, and it was clearly ERB’s intention to superimpose Barsoom onto Martian geography.  ~ [Den Valdron](http://www.erbzine.com/mag14/1402.html) from the [Geographers of Mars Series](http://www.erbzine.com/mag14/1419.html)

Since this first map, many more fanciful maps have been draw and created and even though the original mapping of Mars to Barsoom is considered to have been a failure, it did not stop writers from creating new maps and imagining new tales on Burrough's Barsoom.

Comment: I just saw this question and it makes me feel good there are others who know enough about Barsoom to have given a good answer here.  Sometimes it feels like I'm the only one who remembers some older SF stories and characters.

Comment: I think I am as old as anyone can be here. The Old School science fiction had its issues, but in many ways was still brilliant.

Comment: I remember the old school too; now get off my lawn :)